# Python Selenium get current window handle

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Selenium for Java and Ruby have methods to get current window handle.

For example, in Java it's pointed [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#getWindowHandle()).

In the same time Pythonic version of Selenium has no such method.

1. Maybe it's inside, but I don't see it?
2. If it's skipped, is it reasonable and how to make workaround for it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is [`current_window_handle` property](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.current_window_handle) available on the `WebDriver` instance:

```
driver.current_window_handle
```

Demo:

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>>
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')
>>> 
>>> driver.current_window_handle
CDwindow-B22C1E54-977D-4B2A-8048-E9C73999E9C7
```

To get the name of the window in python but using javascript you can do this in python: ( I looked for this everywhere, but no answer was given for this)

```
window_title = driver.execute_script("return window.document.title") 

window_name = driver.execute_script("return window.name") # e.g. 'win1'
```

Comment: Thanks! No ideas how I skipped it :)

Comment: How can I get the text of that window handle?

Comment: @AdamMc331 hi if you mean, window_name, you can use javascript. i have edited the answer hope it helps. `window_name = driver.execute_script("return window.name") # e.g. 'win1'`