# Selected text with Selenium and Python?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, browser

In the web console, getting the selected (highlighted) text is a simple manner

```
window.getSelection().toString()
```

How about doing this in a headless browser? In particular, I'm using selenium with its python API. I cannot find methods similar to `getSelection()` around `driver`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

For example, suppose I have selected/highlighted (with the cursor) the string `"suppose I have "` on this page, the desired output should be `"suppose I have "`. In case no text is selected/highlighted, return the empty string `""`.

Comment: What text do you want to extract?

Comment: The selected (highlighted) text.

Comment: @Student : Could you update your question with expected output and element you are trying to fetch/extract? may be html text or snapshot.

Comment: How you can get selection if there is no selection?

Comment: @KunduK editted accordingly. gapsf in case no selection is made, return the empty string.

Answer (score 0):

The answer I found is to execute Javascript directly within selenium. For example, to fulfill what I want, run the following script.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
# Manually highlight some text with your cursor.
driver.execute_script("return window.getSelection().toString()")
```

Slightly unrelated but useful: This works within the currently selected window. To switch among different windows, see [1].

- [1] [Python Selenium get current window handle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27645492/python-selenium-get-current-window-handle)